# Making custom grid-like layout on android - inflate first three elements with different layout

Tags: android, layout, grid

I am trying to make a layout which has the gridView characteristics (adapter, scrolable..) but also to be able to put elements that are different from others. It should look like this.

[image]

and when the `Add` button is clicked another two elements should appear, like this:

[image]

I have tried a lot of things, so any idea is appreciated.

**EDIT**

currently I have a gridview with custom tiles with checkmarks. I can put some code but not a lot since I'm under a tight contract.

```
public class ItemsGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<Items> Items;
    Items oneItem;
    Context ctx;
    DisplayImage displayImageTask;
    public ItemsGridAdapter(Context ctx, List<Items> Itemslist){
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.Items = Itemslist;
        oneItem = new Items();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return Items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(row == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.Items, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        oneItem = Items.get(position);
        holder.ItemsId.setText(String.valueOf(oneItem.getItemsId()));
        holder.ItemsName.setText(oneItem.getName());
        displayImageTask = (DisplayImage) new DisplayImage(holder.ItemsPic).execute(oneItem.getItems_icon());
        return row;
    }

    class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView ItemsName;
        TextView ItemsId;
        ImageView ItemsPic;
        ViewHolder(View v)
        {
            ItemsName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtItemsName);
            ItemsId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtItemsId);
            ItemsPic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ItemsTile);
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have a single item layout, which is a box with a checkmark in the top-right corner as displayed on the pictures, and this is my gridView:

```
<GridView
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/itemGrid"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:stretchMode="none"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:columnWidth="@dimen/item_tile_dimen"
                >
            </GridView>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please, post some code so that there is something to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary solution achieved. I am loading the grid view with list of objects (`List<Object>`) which contains two types of objects, one for buttons and other for content. Main logic was found in the Kyogs [blog](http://kyogs.blogspot.in/2014/06/the-use-of-getviewtypecount-and.html).

Bad part is that after button click when I have to hide or show items, I reload gridview with fresh data. I'll optimize it in the future.